# How do I use GMP to create a floating-point array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, gmp

(Warning: I'm a beginner so some of what I say or do may be improper convention)

I had a functional program with the following code at the beginning.

```
    long double p1[] = { 1,0.708894879,0.264150943,0.105121294,0.525,0.437,0.916,0.237516005,1,0.516431925,1,0.799001248,0.436363636,0.45631068,0.4484375,0.366459627,0.369811321 };
    long double p2[] = { 1,0.529569892,0.346774194,0.107526882,0.587,0.353,0.885,0.475672215934624,1,0.446280992,1,0.678756477,0.585185185,0.489552239,0.408396947,0.266129032,0.463316583 };
    long double p3[] = { 1,0.52,0.163333333,0.07,0.516,0.402,0.816,0.667733676304516,1,0.518375242,1,0.761016949,0.462686567,0.445783133,0.416481069,0.368794326,0.557907845579078 };
    long double p4[] = { 1,0.53038674,0.367403315,0.121546961,0.551,0.274,0.736,0.899487836785253,1,0.268817204,1,0.681481481,0.36,0.382352941,0.27173913,0.209302326,0.0978260869565217 };
    long double p5[] = { 1,0.624203822,0.382165605,0.248407643,0.549,0.285,0.692,1.0,1,0.621212121,1,0.934131737,0.390243902,0.24,0.275641026,0.090909091,0.143968871595331 };
    long double* p[] = { &p1[17], &p2[17], &p3[17], &p4[17], &p5[17], &p6[17] };
```

Unfortunately, the "long double" datatype was not big enough once I expanded each of these arrays to a size greater than 17, and my program malfunctioned.

I learned that the next step was to use the GMP library. I have implemented the GMP library, but I can not figure out how to use it to replace "long double." I have particularly been unable to set the array values.

The GMP documentation says: "An mpf_t object must be initialized before storing the first value in it." So, I initialized my objects as such:

```
    mpf_t p1[17];
    mpf_t p2[17];
    mpf_t p3[17];
    mpf_t p4[17];
    mpf_t p5[17];
    mpf_t p6[17];
    mpf_t p[17];
```

There are no apparent errors with this code.

However, I don't see a way to explicitly set the array values like I did in my original code. I've looked over the documentation but all of the relevant functions appear to only take two argumetns.

Maybe I have to do something like:

```
    mpf_set_d (p1[1], 1);
    mpf_set_d (p1[2], 0.708894879);
    ...
```

But I'm assuming that that's not the case. While it works, it would be extremely tedious and involve a lot of copy-pasting, which I've been told is a sign of bad techniques.

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `mpf_t p1[17];` doesn't initialize anything.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie When GMP talks about initialization, it means https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Floats.html#Initializing-Floats.

Comment: Use the C++ interface `mpf_float` after including `<gmpxx.h>`.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard about loops? They are wonderful :-)

```
static const double p1_init[] = { 1,0.708894879,0.264150943,0.105121294,0.525,0.437,0.916,0.237516005,1,0.516431925,1,0.799001248,0.436363636,0.45631068,0.4484375,0.366459627,0.369811321 };

mpf_t p1[17];

for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
{
   mpf_init (p1[i]);
   mpf_set_d (p1[i], p1_init[i]);
}
```

Now you just have to extend this to `p2`, `p3` etc..

Two comments on the above code:

1. declaring `p1_init[]` as `static const` is just to make the code "cleaner".
   As a beginner, you can probably drop the `static const` here if you haven't
   learned about it yet.
2. `c` arrays are zero based. All sane programming languages have zero based arrays. 
   That means that in an array with 17 elements, the first element has index 0, and
   the last element has index 16. There is no element with index 17

Comment: It's looks like it's recommended to create C++ wrappers or use one from boost for C++. Every `mpf_t` requires `mpf_clear` if `mpf_init` was called for it. Essentially it's construction and destruction of non-trivial object done in C.